# Realtime filtering of listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, filter

I would like to be able to filter a listbox containing 1000 strings, each 50 - 4000 characters in length, as the user types in the textbox without a delay.

I'm currently using a timer which updates the listbox after the `TextChanged` event of the textbox has not been triggered in 300ms.  However, this is quite jerky and the ui sometimes freezes momentarily.

What is the normal way of implementing functionality similar to this?

Edit: I'm using winforms and .net2.

Thanks

Here is a stripped down version of the code I am currently using:

```
string separatedSearchString = this.filterTextBox.Text;

List<string> searchStrings = new List<string>(separatedSearchString.Split(new char[] { ';' }, 
                                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

//this is a member variable which is cleared when new data is loaded into the listbox
if (this.unfilteredItems.Count == 0)
{
    foreach (IMessage line in this.logMessagesListBox.Items)
    {
        this.unfilteredItems.Add(line);
    }
}

StringComparison comp = this.IsCaseInsensitive
                        ? StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
                        : StringComparison.Ordinal;

List<IMessage> resultingFilteredItems = new List<IMessage>();

foreach (IMessage line in this.unfilteredItems)
{
    string message = line.ToString();
    if(searchStrings.TrueForAll(delegate(string item) { return message.IndexOf(item, comp) >= 0; }))
    {
        resultingFilteredItems.Add(line);
    }
}

this.logMessagesListBox.BeginUpdate();
this.logMessagesListBox.Items.Clear();
this.logMessagesListBox.Items.AddRange(resultingFilteredItems.ToArray());
this.logMessagesListBox.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: ASP.NET or WinForms or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. Make you UI more responsive with a second thread which takes cares of the filtering. A really great new technology is Reactive Extensions (Rx) which will do exactly what you need.

   I can give a example. I guess you use WinForms? A part of you code would help.

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

   Here is a little teaser:

   ```
   Observable.Context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
   var textchanged = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(textBox1, "TextChanged");

   textchanged.Throttle(300).Subscribe(ea =>
   {
       //Here 300 milisec. is gone without TextChanged fired. Do the filtering
   });
   ```
2. Make your filtering algorithm more efficient. Do you filter with something like StartWith or something like Contains?

   You can use something like a suffix tree or all the prefixes of the list items and make a lookup. But describe what you need precisely and I will find something simple - yet efficient enough. The UI is pretty heavy if you want to show 100.000 items in the ListBox but if you only take - say 100 - it is fast (uncomment the .Take(100) line). It can also be made a little better if the searching is done in another thread. It should be easy with Rx but I haven't tried it.

**Update**

Try something like this. It works fine here with 100.000 elements which is ~10 characters long. It uses Reactive Extensions (the link before).

Also, the algorithm is naive and can be made a lot faster if you want to.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Observable.Context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    var textchanged = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(textBox1, "TextChanged");

    //You can change 300 to something lower to make it more responsive
    textchanged.Throttle(300).Subscribe(filter);
}

private void filter(IEvent<EventArgs> e)
{
    var searchStrings = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    //my randStrings is your unfiltered messages

    StringComparison comp = StringComparison.CurrentCulture; //Do what you want here

    var resultList = from line in randStrings
                     where searchStrings.All(item => line.IndexOf(item, comp) >= 0)
                     select line;

    //A lot faster but only gives you first 100 finds then uncomment:
    //resultList = resultList.Take(100);

    listBox1.BeginUpdate();
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.AddRange(resultList.ToArray());
    listBox1.EndUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've updated my question with a condensed version of my code.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the example code.  However, as far as I can tell, the reactive extensions are only available for .net3.5 and up.  Are there any .net2 equivalents I could use?

Comment: Hhm pretty much everything have to be rewritten :D LINQ is not in .Net framework 2.0 either. Can I see the old delay timer you wrote? If it is enough, you could cut so only the first 100 in your result list is provided to Items.AddRange - it will properly be a lot faster than if you want to show 1000 elements.

Comment: Maybe the other answer will provide what you need? I'm not a day-to-day WinForms programmer so I have not used BindingSource.

Answer (score 2):

Azerax's answer is the right one with the new release of RX.

When you want to seperate the code from the UI elements, you can have:

```
input.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(filterHandler, errorMsg);
```

This will bring the notification back to the UI thread. Otherwise, the throttle(*) will not effect.

Answer (score 1):

First off, thanks to @lasseespeholt, for getting me started on this idea, very new to me. But indeed Rx is very interesting to do, makes life much easier :)

I had to implement a similar thing with a treeview containing nodes (only parent level) being filtered by the text changed event in WinForms.

The app kept crashing on me, for some odd reason.

I found a PDF on the MSDN site @ [MSDN Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577611) ([PDF download link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208528) - refer page 25) which was tackling a similar problem and had described a Cross thread access issue.

Here is the fix it provided which worked for me, the solution is to also use ObserveOn before you subscribe.

Here is sample code, which utilizes the later version of Rx - 1.0.10605.1

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Attach an event handler for the text changed event
    /// </summary>
    private void attachTextChangedEventHandler()
    {            
    var input = (from evt in Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(textBox1,"TextChanged")
    .select ((TextBox)evt.Sender).Text)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    input.ObserveOn(treeView1).Subscribe(filterHandler, errorMsg);
    }
    private void filterHandler(string filterText)
    {
        Loadtreeview(filterText);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using a BindingSource for your List. It can do what you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx

An example using a DataTable, but the same stuff can apply to a List.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya3sah92.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not to high-jack this thread but everyone suggested LINQ styled developments or additional resources to add to the library overhead of the application.

What i did was define a List(Of) collection to hold the original list of information that i end up loading into the ListBox and a Filtered List(Of) collection to hold the resulting filtered subset.

I did utilize the RegEx namespace to do the filtration but you could use the pattern system inherent with the String framework.  Here is the code that i used to get the job done.

```
   Private Sub txtNetRegex_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtNetRegex.TextChanged
      If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNetRegex.Text) Then
         btnNetALLToDB.Enabled = False
      Else
         btnNetALLToDB.Enabled = True

         Dim reg As New Regex(txtNetRegex.Text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

         Me._netFilteredNames = New List(Of String)

         For Each s As String In Me._netNames
            On Error Resume Next
            If (reg.IsMatch(s)) Then
               Me._netFilteredNames.Add(s)
            End If
         Next

         LoadNetBox()
      End If
   End Sub
   Private Sub LoadNetBox()
      lbxNetwork.Items.Clear()
      lbxNetwork.Refresh()

      Dim lst As List(Of String)
      If Me.chkEnableNetFilter.Checked And (Me._netFilteredNames IsNot Nothing) Then
         lst = Me._netFilteredNames
      Else
         lst = Me._netNames
      End If

      If lst IsNot Nothing Then
         For Each s As String In lst
            lbxNetwork.Items.Add(s)
         Next
      End If

      lbxNetwork.Refresh()
   End Sub
```